# Is $|z^n| = |z|^n$ if $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was looking some properties of complex modules and says that $|z_{1} z_{2}| = |z_{1}||z_{2}|$ but if that is true then let $z = a+bi$ then $|z^2| = |z||z| = |z|^2 = z \overset{-}{z}$.

Comment: Yes, and $\lvert z^n\rvert = \lvert z\rvert^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $z^n$ makes sense.

Comment: Yes, try induction and use $|z_1||z_2|=|z_1z_2|$.

Comment: Hint: Rewrite $z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $z=re^{i \theta}$ in which case $|z|=r$. Now, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $|z^n|=|r^ne^{in \theta}|=r^n=|z|^n$.

Comment: As simple as it gets. +1. And this argument holds unchanged for $n\in\mathbb Z$ (provided $z\neq 0$).

Answer (score 0):

we have $$|(a+bi)^2|=\sqrt{a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2+4a^2b^2}=a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$$
use induction to prove it for all $$n$$

Answer (score 0):

let us use the polar form

if $z=re^{it}$  then $|z|=r$.

for every integer or real $n$,

$z^n=r^ne^{int}$.

we see that

$|z^n|=r^n=|z|^n$ since

$|e^{int}|=|cos(nt)+isin(nt)|=1$.